Back EMF-Based Speed Measurement of Single-Phase Induction Motor
I want to determine the speed of a single-phase fan directly on the PCB by measuring the current and voltage values without using any external sensors. My plan is to utilize an ACS712 IC as the current sensor and a simple voltage divider circuit, or even an analog isolator, for the voltage measurement. I aim to convert the measured current and voltage values into a meaningful speed (RPM) reading using a microcontroller (STM32). Although I have not designed the hardware yet, I am currently focusing on the software development as a preparatory step.
Through my research, I have identified the parameters necessary for calculating back EMF, which include:
Stator impedance (Zₛ): This consists of resistance (Rₛ) and reactance (Xₛ) components.
The number of poles in the motor (P).
Magnetic flux constant (Φ) or motor constant (k).
Rated voltage (Vₙ).
Rated current (Iₙ).
Rotor impedance (optional).
Rated frequency of the motor (f).
The parameters for the AC motor I plan to use are as follows:
Rated voltage (Vₙ): 230V
Rated current (Iₙ): 3A
Rated power (Pₙ): 500W
Frequency (f): 50 Hz
Power factor (cosθ): 0.85
The impedance components are not specified by the manufacturer, so I am calculating the impedance indirectly using the following formulas:
Apparent Power (S):
S = Vₙ × Iₙ = 230V × 3A = 690 VA
Reactive Power (Q):
Q = √(S² - Pₙ²) = √(690² - 500²) ≈ 461 VAR
Impedance Angle (θ):
cosθ = Pₙ / S = 500 / 690 ≈ 0.725
θ = arccos(0.725) ≈ 43.5°
Total Impedance (Z):
Z = Vₙ / Iₙ = 230V / 3A ≈ 76.67 Ω
Resistance (R) and Reactance (X):
R = Z × cosθ = 76.67 × 0.725 ≈ 55.6 Ω
X = Z × sinθ = 76.67 × sin(43.5°) ≈ 52.8 Ω
Results:
Resistance (R) ≈ 55.6 Ω
Reactance (X) ≈ 52.8 Ω
Total Impedance (Z) ≈ 76.67 Ω
Based on these values, I have created the following example and draft code:
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "math.h"

// Maximum voltage and current values to be measured from ADC
#define MAX_VOLTAGE 230.0   // Rated voltage (V)
#define MAX_CURRENT 3.0     // Rated current (A)
#define MAX_ADC_VALUE 4095  // Maximum value of 12-bit ADC

// Electrical parameters of the motor
#define MOTOR_RESISTANCE 55.6   // Stator resistance (Ohm)
#define MOTOR_REACTANCE 52.8    // Stator reactance (Ohm)
#define MOTOR_IMPEDANCE 76.67   // Total impedance of the motor (Ohm)
#define POWER_FACTOR 0.85       // Power factor

// Motor constant and number of poles (for example, number of poles for fan motor can be 2)
#define MOTOR_CONSTANT 1.0      // Motor design constant (approximately)
#define MOTOR_POLES 2           // Number of poles of the motor

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc2;

// Function to calculate Back EMF
float calculate_back_emf(float voltage, float current) {
    // Calculate voltage drop based on impedance and current
    float voltage_drop = current * MOTOR_IMPEDANCE;
    
    // Back EMF is obtained by subtracting the voltage drop from the supply voltage
    float back_emf = voltage - voltage_drop;
    
    return back_emf;
}

// Function to calculate motor speed in RPM
float calculate_motor_speed(float back_emf) {
    // Synchronous speed is calculated based on number of poles and grid frequency
    float motor_speed = (120 * back_emf) / (MOTOR_CONSTANT * MOTOR_POLES);
    
    return motor_speed;
}

// Function to read voltage from ADC
float read_voltage() {
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    uint32_t adc_value = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    
    // Convert ADC value to voltage
    float voltage = (adc_value / (float)MAX_ADC_VALUE) * MAX_VOLTAGE;
    return voltage;
}

// Function to read current from ADC
float read_current() {
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    uint32_t adc_value = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc2);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc2);
    
    // Convert ADC value to current
    float current = (adc_value / (float)MAX_ADC_VALUE) * MAX_CURRENT;
    return current;
}

int main(void) {
    // Initialize the STM32 system
    HAL_Init();
    
    // Configure ADC and other peripherals here
    // (This part can be automatically generated by STM32 CubeMX)

    while (1) {
        // Measure voltage and current
        float voltage = read_voltage();
        float current = read_current();
        
        // Calculate Back EMF
        float back_emf = calculate_back_emf(voltage, current);
        
        // Calculate motor speed (in RPM)
        float motor_speed = calculate_motor_speed(back_emf);
        
        // You can send speed information via UART or log it elsewhere
        printf("Motor Speed: %.2f RPM\n", motor_speed);
        
        HAL_Delay(1000); // Wait for 1 second
    }
}

This code is a preliminary draft and has not been tested in any real system. However, I have some doubts about the simplicity of the process and would like to seek your insights before proceeding with any testing. I would greatly appreciate any additional information or thoughts you might have regarding this code.
Thank you!

Yet , no idea ?
